# insert ... on duplicate key update with null values for not-null column

Tags: mysql

I have a following example table:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+-----+
| Field | Type      | Null  | PK  |
+-------+-----------+-------+-----+
| id    | int       | NO    | PRI |
| numb  | int       | NO    |     |
| text  | text      | NO    |     |
+-------+-----------+-------+-----+
```

In which I'm trying to update several rows with one query:

```
INSERT INTO example_table 
VALUES (1, 100, null), (2, 100, 'abc') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
numb = VALUES(numb), text = IFNULL(VALUES(text), text);
```

MySQL doesn't allows to execute this query because one of VALUES blocks contains null value for not-null column (`text` column). But, I am passing only data for existing rows which will 100% trigger "ON DUPLICATE KEY" section, which have additional null check.

Is there any way I can disable this check?

I know I can use multiple UPDATE statements with different set of columns.
But I am interested specifically in `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query.

Comment: Pass a blank string as opposed to null as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shadow suggested, using empty string will do the job just perfect!

```
INSERT INTO example_table 
VALUES (1, 100, ''), (2, 100, 'abc') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
numb = VALUES(numb), text = IF(VALUES(text) = '', text, VALUES(text));
```